# How to unit test ChatterActivity?

Tags: unit-test

I need to perform some testing using ChatterActivity records. I try creating a user and inserting a chatter post as that user, but when I then query I don't get any ChatterActivity for that user. What am I missing?

```
@IsTest
public static void testChatterActivity() {
    Profile profile = UserRegAdminService.getProfile('Standard User');
    User user = new User(Username = 'testuser@myapplication.com',
                         Lastname = 'test',
                         Alias = 'test',
                         Email = 'test@test.owner',
                         CommunityNickname = 'anontest',
                         ProfileId = profile.Id,
                         LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                         languagelocalekey='en_US',
                         emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                         timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
    insert user;

    System.runAs(user) {
        insert new FeedItem(ParentId = user.Id, Body = 'body');
    }

    ChatterActivity[] act = [SELECT ParentId, InfluenceRawRank FROM ChatterActivity WHERE ParentId = :user.Id];
    System.assertEquals(1, act.size());
}
```

Comment: To replicate this issue, I copied the same code in my org and it gave me the same error. But when I executed this code by removing runAs function it got worked. So, It might be due to running user permissions for Chatter Activity. Not sure though!